# Sort database table to bring rows having data for all columns first

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-5.7

In MySQL5.7, I have a column having 28 columns and 4000 rows. I want to bring rows having data for all or rows having data for maximum columns first and then for the other rows to progressively follow. How do I achieve this ?

Eg:
Table : Student

| name | age | address |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tan | 10 |  |
| gib | 10 | california |
| hal |  |  |
| pur | 12 |  |

Expected Output: 'gib' should come first, followed by either 'tan' or 'pur' since they both have data for only 1 column, followed by 'hal' which doesn't have any data.

Comment: You mean rows with all 28 columns populated, then 27 populated, etc?  It's possible, but it will be seriously ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Use this `ORDER BY` clause:

```
ORDER BY (column1 IS NOT NULL) + 
         (column2 IS NOT NULL) + 
         (column3 IS NOT NULL) +
         ....................... 
         (column28 IS NOT NULL) DESC;
```

Each of the `columnX IS NOT NULL` expressions evaluates to `1` for `TRUE` or `0` for `FALSE`.
What you get by summing them is the number of *non*-`NULL` columns in each row and you can use this numeric result to sort the rows descending.

Comment: Oooh, this is brilliant.  I had no idea you could do this without 28 case statements. Is this MySQL specific syntax?

Comment: @Andrew I know that SQLite also evaluates boolean expressions as 1 or 0.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `name` column would never have null values, we can try:

```sql
SELECT name, age, address
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    name,
    age IS NULL,      -- non null age first
    age,              -- sort ascending by age
    address IS NULL,  -- non null address first
    address;          -- sort ascending by address
```